# Kentico 11 customapi MapHttpRoute

Tags: kentico

I am looking for a solution in Kentico 11 to add the mapping of our custom API:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute ("customapi", "customapi / {controller} / {id}", new {id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional});
```

I added this line after the OnInit of the template root.master.cs, this working fine on the first load but for the next loads there is this error :

> A road named 'customapi' is already in the road collection. Route
>   names must be unique.

There is an application_start on Kentico where can I add this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `OnInit` event of `Root.master.cs` fires after each load of the page, you would essentially be mapping your route every time the page loads.

You need to be mapping the route on load of the *application*, not the *page*.

[Create a custom module](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/creating-custom-modules/initializing-modules-to-run-custom-code), and set up your routes on init of the module. Modules are initialised when the application starts.

```csharp
using System.Web.Http;
using CMS;
using CMS.DataEngine;

[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(MyCustomModule))]
public class MyCustomModule : Module
{
    public MyCustomModule() : base("MyCustomModule") { }

    // Called when the application starts
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        base.OnInit();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("customapi", "customapi/{controller}/{id}", new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```